# How to access the sub-collection of a queried document in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

**Context**: Below is the screenshot of my collection and document in Firebase Firestore. Basically, every transaction document has its own field and a chat collection inside of it.

**What I need**: My goal is to query the document with a specific handler_id and to access the chat collection inside of it.

**What's happening**: This query only returns the transaction field

```
 db.collection("transaction").where("handler_id", "==", 3)
```

*How can I include the chat collection in the queried document? Do you have any suggestion on how I can structure my data more efficiently?*
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Queries in Firestore are shallow, meaning that when you query for documents via a query you only get the corresponding documents in the collection you are querying and not the documents from their sub-collections.

So you need to first query the parent `transaction` document (which is an asynchronous process), and when you get it, query the sub-collection (which is also an asynchronous process).

If we make the assumption that there is only one document in the `transaction` collection with `handler_id = 3`, you would do something along the following lines:

```
db.collection("transaction").where("handler_id", "==", 3).get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
   return querySnapshot.docs[0].ref.collection('chat').get();
})
.then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

---

If you want to set up a listener to the `chat` subcollection, you just have to call the [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#on-snapshot) method instead of the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) one, as follows:

```
db.collection("transaction").where("handler_id", "==", 3).get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
   querySnapshot.docs[0].ref.collection('chat').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        // Do whatever you want with the querySnapshot
        // E.g. querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {...})
        // or querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {...})
        // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay, I understand that it is not possible to do this in a single query, because Queries in Firestore are shallow. But, is it possible to add an onSnapshot function on the chat collection?

Comment: Subcollections are no different than top level collections for queries and listeners. Just build a reference to it and work with that reference like any other.